# NodeJS Package: error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I have some code that uses an Overwatch API to grab some data. This is what I currently have:

```
OWoverallStats: (playerName, mode, region) => {
    mode = (typeof mode === 'undefined') ? 'competitive' : mode.toLowerCase();
    region = (typeof region === 'undefined') ? 'us' : region.toLowerCase();

    playerName = playerName.replace('#', '-');

    return fetch(`https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/${playerName}/stats`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            return data[region].stats[mode].overall_stats;
        });
}
```

This works fine, providing you enter a playerName that actually exists. The code I used to test this is:

```
core.OWoverallStats('Calvin-1337', 'quickplay', 'eu').then(data => {
    console.log(data.tier) // grandmaster
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

In the actual code,  I can check if the error code is 404 (player doesn't exist) but then I don't know what I can do with that. I don't want to throw an error, or console log it as if someone implemented this say into a Discord Bot, I'd want the person using the code to say what they wanted to do with the error.

Comment: Why not just throw it up to the client if you don't want to handle it?

Comment: @Paul I'm not too sure on how to/what exactly you mean.

Comment: I mean don't catch an error you aren't prepared to handle. If you do, for logging, throw it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetch has a response, if the status is 404 Simply throw an Error. The caller of your code can then catch it and handle however he likes.

**For example, your code:**

```
return fetch(`https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/${playerName}/stats`)
.then((res, meta) => {if (meta.status ===404) throw new Error('NoPlayer')})
```

**The caller of your code:**

```
core.OWoverallStats('Calvin-1337', 'quickplay', 'eu').then(data => {
}).catch(e => {
//this is where he can handle the error flexibly
});
```

You may see [other error handling practices here](http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practices-of-node-js-error-handling/)

Comment: I feel so stupid, I had this but I thought that it would throw that error no matterwhat I put in the `catch` lol. Thanks!

Comment: seriously, we all learn everyday, just keep learning and improving :)